# If $f$ is non-negative and $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}2^{kp}\omega(2^{k})<\infty$ then $f$ is in $L^{p}(\mathbb R^{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $f$ is non-negative and $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}2^{kp}\omega(2^{k})<\infty$ then $f$ is in $L^{p}(\mathbb R^{n})$
,where $p\in(1,\infty)$ and $\omega(\alpha)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\{x:f(x)>\alpha\}$ for all real $\alpha$.

Here's my working :
\begin{align}
p\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\omega(\alpha)d\alpha&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}p\int_{2^{k}}^{2^{k+1}}\alpha^{p-1}\omega(\alpha)d\alpha\\
&\le\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}p\int_{2^{k}}^{2^{k+1}}\alpha^{p-1}\omega(2^{k})d\alpha\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\omega(2^{k})\int_{2^{k}}^{2^{k+1}}p\alpha^{p-1}d\alpha\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\omega(2^{k})\bigg(\alpha^{p}|_{2^{k}}^{2^{k+1}}\, \bigg)\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\omega(2^{k})\bigg(2^{p}\cdot2^{kp}-2^{kp}\bigg)\\
&=\bigg(2^{p}-1\bigg)\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}2^{kp}\omega(2^{k})<\infty
\end{align}
But

\begin{align}
p\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\omega(\alpha)d\alpha&=p\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\int_{\mathbb R^{n}}
\chi_{\{x\,:f(x)>\alpha\}}\,dx\,d\alpha\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}p\alpha^{p-1}\chi_{\{x\,:f(x)>\alpha\}}\,d\alpha\,dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^{n}}\int_{0}^{f(x)}p\alpha^{p-1}d\alpha\,dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^{n}}f^{p}(x)\,dx\\
&=\lVert f\rVert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R^{n}\,)}^{p}
\end{align}

,where the second part of the second equality holds by Tonelli theorem.Then our conclusion follows.

Please check my proof for validity if you have the time.Thanks  for considering my request. Any advice will be the greatest appreciation. Thank you.

Comment: Your proof is sound.